# jQuery autocomplete show results 'containing' query not begining with query

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

jQuery autocomplete plugin shows results that begin with the query you type into a search box. How would you amend the plugin to allow you to show results that contain the query you are typing? for example, i am searching for people, i want to be able to type either a firstname or a surname, i type 'and' i want it to show Adam **And**erson, James **And**erson, **And**y Smith

Comment: Which plugin exactly? In JQuery, there are 5 plugins for every functionality.

Comment: Using version 1.1 - as Pointy mentions below,  i was missing an option. thanks.

Comment: version 1.1 of `what`?  There's a built-in autocomplete in jQuery UI, it is at version 1.8rc3.  There are a number of third-party add-on autocomplete widgets.  You never specified which one you are using.

Comment: check out my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971351/jquery-autocomplete-matchcontains-not-working/7976652#7976652

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the "autocomplete" plugin I use already has a "matchContains" option. If that's set to true, then it behaves exactly as you describe.

http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm